# Remove animation from WP theme (css)

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a Wordpress template with an animation on the frontpage. The animation loads the frontpage content (banner and newsletter) when you scroll. I wan't to remove the animation, but I can't find out in which CSS file the animation script is hided. Can anybpody please help me?

Thanks :))

http://funwithfelix.com/

Comment: Are you using slider revolution plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Found inside helper.js

```
// Initializing waypoints to show/hide flowign panel above header
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.site-header').waypoint(function(direction) {
            if (direction == 'down') {
                $('.panel-hidden').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.panel-hidden').fadeOut();               
            }
        }, {
          offset: function() {
            return -$(this).height();
          }
        });
    });
});
```